# How to update locale where location is empty

Tags: mysql

well I have this

table users , field "locale" that's empty and "location"=Paris 
what command to use in sql to update the locale to FR where "location"=Paris

Comment: You should really grab some book about SQL. BTW is location empty or is location "Paris"? And what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

Use [update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

```
Update users set locale='FR' where location='Paris';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update users set locale='FR' where location='Paris'
```

### [Check out Here for more on UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Update users SET locale='FR' WHERE location='Paris';
```

Comment: Yeah, one more new aspect to this question.